# An ordering on a set A

Tags: order-theory

Let $A= \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.
An ordering on A is defined  $x\leq y $ $\Leftrightarrow$ $y \; \text{is multiple of} 
 \;x$.

Find the maximal and minimal elements of A. 
$2$ is the minimum or not ?
$5$ is a maximal element ?
I don't have any idea for this question.

Thanks your helping.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the question? That is a fine partial order.

Comment: Find the maximal and minimum elements of A. 2 is the minimum or not ? And 5 is maximal ?

Comment: Please edit that into your question

Answer (score 0):

The minimal elements of $A$ are those which do not have any divisors in $A$: by inspection these are $2,3,5,$ and $7$.

The maximal elements of $A$ are those which do not divide any other elements of $A$: by inspection these are $7,8,9,$ and $10$.

Comment: I do not understand the part of maximal. A number is both maximal and minimal in the same time. Is it possible ?

Comment: What is your definition of maximal/minimal? I used the one found on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements

Comment: But $5$ divides $10$.